# How To use DistanceMatrix Api in Spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I have a requirement to use DestanceMatrix API to calculate the distance between origin to destination.

can anyone help me to implement this functionality in the spring boot Application?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void distanceMatrixTest() {
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY_STATIC).build();

    DistanceMatrixRow[] rows = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context)
            .origins(new LatLng(3.1054104954261823, 101.39172498261695))
            .destinations(new LatLng(3.0651174019721434, 101.79107501515256),
                    new LatLng(3.0362824146932934, 101.75871771663888),
                    new LatLng(3.0717816850989803, 101.75618972318607))
            .awaitIgnoreError().rows;

    if (rows.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < rows[i].elements.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Distance for j === " + j + " - " + rows[i].elements[j].distance.humanReadable);
                System.out.println("Distance for j === " + j + " - " + rows[i].elements[j].distance.inMeters);
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Duration for j === " + j + " - " + rows[i].elements[j].duration.humanReadable);
                System.out.println("Duration for j === " + j + " - " + rows[i].elements[j].duration.inSeconds);
                System.out.println("Status for j === " + j + " - " + rows[i].elements[j].status);
                System.out.println("------------ NEXT Record ----------------");
            }

        }

    }

    // Invoke .shutdown() after your application is done making requests
    context.shutdown();

}
```